# RxSchedulerPurge always take periodic cpu load even in the background on Android

Tags: android, rx-java

When I used Android studio method trace to analyze my app's battery drain problem, I observed periodic cpu load after the app was paused with the home button. This load is caused by threads that are part of RxJava.[image: method trace taked 2 minutes after app paused with home button]

The code get from RxJava github source that may cause the problem.

```
public static void start() {
    for (;;) {
        ScheduledExecutorService curr = PURGE_THREAD.get();
        if (curr != null && !curr.isShutdown()) {
            return;
        }
        ScheduledExecutorService next = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, new RxThreadFactory("RxSchedulerPurge"));
        if (PURGE_THREAD.compareAndSet(curr, next)) {

            next.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduledTask(), PURGE_PERIOD_SECONDS, PURGE_PERIOD_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            return;
        } else {
            next.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/schedulers/SchedulerPoolFactory.java

I tried to change the purge period time, 
I add the following code in my app's application onCreate, but it seems not work.

```
System.setProperty("rx2.purge-period-seconds", "3600");
```

Comment: You should add that way before any Rx component is initialized, for example, as a `static { }` initialization block.

Comment: @akarnokd I followed your recommend and set the system property in static initialization block before Rx components is initialized, but nothing changed. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Place a breakpoint in the factory to see what gets it initialized prematurely.

Comment: @akarnokd Thanks, I found the problem,but it's a little wired. If I only set the "rx2.purge-period-seconds" property without set the "rx2.purge-enabled"  to "true", the "rx2.purge-period-seconds" will be ignored, I don't understand Why there should be a repeat ScheulerTask when purgeEnable is false by default.Repeat work that always run even in  background is not acceptable for android applications.

Comment: There is a logical error in that initialization block; I'll post a PR to fix that.

Comment: @akarnokd That will be great.Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: What would the implications of disabling the RxSchedulerPurge thread or increasing the value of rx2.purge-period-seconds @akarnokd be ?  Thanks very much

Comment: If you disable or delay the purge, if you use a lot of timed tasks that get cancelled a lot (timeouts, interval, etc.) it may lead to OOME. This is an unfortunate relic from when Android started off with Java 6.